# Creation of the virtual directory mydomain.com

Tags: iis

Open exist solution

> Add->Exist project-> select mySubProject.csproj

This the window comes in;

[image]

I have searched it and think its about site-name in
**.vs\SolutionName\config\applicationhost.config** file;

```
<sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <!-- To enable logging, please change the below attribute "enabled" to "true" -->
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%AppData%\Microsoft\IISExpressLogs" enabled="false" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%AppData%\Microsoft" enabled="false" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

And this is mySubProject.csproj;

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>11066</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl><<mydomain.com>></IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Comment: Create an empty project to compare and you should easily observe the cause. `<IISUrl><<mydomain.com>></IISUrl>` is the part that VS dislikes the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the `IIS Express` settings. Try to navigate the `.vs/mysolutionname/config` folder of your current solution and delete `applicationhost.config` file, which has all sites of Visual Studio configured. Then restart VS and add the existing project again.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.